# AngularJS - ng-repeat not working with a map-entry named length and value 0

Tags: angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to show Events with Subevents I got from an API as JSON

```
[
{
"class":"de.ff.prg.EventItem",
"id":27667,
"additional_info":null,
"comments":null,
"event":{"class":"Event","id":27657},
"length":0,
"runningorder":0,
"screening":{"class":"Screening","id":27529},
"title_eng":"'71",
"title_ger":"'71",
"venue":{"class":"Venue","id":1}},

{"class":"de.ff.prg.EventItem",
"id":27676,
"additional_info":null,
"comments":null,
"event":{"class":"Event","id":27657},
"length":5,
"runningorder":0,
"screening":null,
"title_eng":"NEW",
"title_ger":"NEW",
"venue":{"class":"Venue","id":8}
}
]
```

In order to display the fields of the items in rows and not in columns, I have nested two tables with ng-repeat so that I get a table of tables.

```
<!--Items-->
<table>
    <thead>
        <td colspan="6" style="background-color: #b9da73">
            <button class="btnAdd" ng-click="addAndEditEventItem()">Add Item</button>
        </td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="item in eventItems">
            <h1>{{eventItems.length}}</h1>
            <th>

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #c0da86">{{item.runningorder}}</td>
                    <td colspan="4" style="background-color: #c0da86">
                        <button class="btnAdd" ng-click="deleteEventItem(item.id)">Delete Item</button>
                    </td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {{item}}
                    <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">
                        <th colspan="2" style="background-color: #ceeca1">{{key}}</th>
                        <th colspan="4" style="font-weight: normal;">{{value}} </th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Up until now this was no problem, but somewhere along the way I have lost the possibility to display the body of the first sub-table (all other rows render fine). I have inserted `{{item}}` before the body tag and it shows the missing data, so it's there all right.

Any ideas? Or do you need to see the other code to tell? I have no clue...

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5B2F/1/)

Comment: To start with your HTML is invalid, you miss `tr` from `thead > tr > td`, `h1` shouldn't be a child to `tr`, fix it and maybe make a fiddle or plunker to have a better image

Comment: Here's a fiddle on this [(my first Fiddle)] (http://jsfiddle.net/j5B2F/1/) (also added in question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting case. 
Empirically, I found that this is because of

```
"length":0
```

Just looked into angular source code and found that it transforms object's properties in repeat to an array, and then takes it's length property to iterate through it.

```
...ngRepeatDirective...
              if (isArrayLike(collection)) {
                collectionKeys = collection;
                trackByIdFn = trackByIdExpFn || trackByIdArrayFn;
              } else {
                trackByIdFn = trackByIdExpFn || trackByIdObjFn;
                // if object, extract keys, sort them and use to determine order of iteration over obj props
                collectionKeys = [];
                for (key in collection) {
                  if (collection.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.charAt(0) != '$') {
                    collectionKeys.push(key);
                  }
                }
                collectionKeys.sort();
              }

              arrayLength = collectionKeys.length; <<<--- HERE

              // locate existing items
              length = nextBlockOrder.length = collectionKeys.length; <<<--- AND HERE
```

So nothing really happens.

Seems like a bug actually. I've posted an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8000).

Just try then iterating through your array and change name of this property. Like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.eventItems.length; i++){
    $scope.eventItems[i].itemLength = $scope.eventItems[i].length;
    delete $scope.eventItems[i].length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that first thing tomorrow

Comment: Yes, I have eliminated the key and it works. I have also checked with replacing the value directly on server-side outout. Any value but 0 is OK. Thanks for raising an issue, I'll work around it until it's fixed.